# How to convert object class to arrayList ? java

Tags: java

I have this code :

```
ArrayList<Integer> users = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Map <String,Object> hashMap = new HashMap <String,Object> ();

hashMap.put("users",user);

// now I want to get users as array list
 hashMap.get("users")[i];//error
```

How to users as array ? thank you

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray()

Comment: 1) Change the value type of the map to `List`. 2) User `hashMap.get("users").get(0)`

Comment: Why on earth are you storing the list as an Object???

Comment: @Andreas no it's not duplicated, I want to convert specific value

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Integer> users = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Map<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
hashMap.put("users",user);
....
....
....
List<Integer> users = (List<Integer>)hashMap.get("users"); //assuming this is another method and 'users' is not defined here yet
Integer[] usersArray = users.toArray(new Integer[users.size()]);
System.out.println("" + usersArray[i]);
```

Please note that this is an atrocity and you shouldn't be storing that List as an Object, you are pretty much circumventing what Generics are for.

Comment: agreed, but he already has users as a variable, I'm not even sure why he wants to put it into a map and get it out of it like that. Or store it as an object. I'm confused about the purpose, really, but this should work.

Comment: @user2864740 'mkay done

Answer (score 2):

This code will work if you want to access it as an ArrayList:

```
List<Integer> users = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Map<String, List<Integer>> hashMap = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>> ();
hashMap.put("users",users);
hashMap.get("users");
```

Your code won't work since you were storing it as an Object. So you would need a cast. And even then you use `[]` for arrays, not ArrayLists

If you want to use it as an array you can change the last line to:

```
hashMap.get("users").toArray()
```

And then you can use `[1]`, or just do .get(1) on the initial code.

Alternatively, if you want to use hashMap as a property bag as someone validly mentioned you would need to do a cast:

```
((ArrayList<Integer>) hashMap.get("users"))
```

Then you can use users as an `ArrayList` as you are getting an `Object` by default from the `HashMap`.

Comment: If it's a property bag, he should use a class unless he is sending this to JavaScript world, which I doubt he is.

Comment: @user2864740 you raise a valid point so I've updated my answer to also help him if that is his intention.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is `ArrayList` and not array,You can get it like this-

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
  ArrayList<Integer> users = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  users.add(5);
  users.add(10);

  Map <String,Object> hashMap = new HashMap <String,Object> ();

  hashMap.put("users",users);

  ArrayList<Integer> no =  ((ArrayList<Integer>) hashMap.get("users"));

   for (Integer integer : no) {
    System.out.println(integer);
   }
}
```

output-

```
5
10
```

Now to convert ArrayList to Array -

```
Integer[] arr = no.toArray(new Integer[no.size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like following

```
List<Users> usersList = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String,List<Users>> hashMap = new HashMap <> ();
hashMap.put("user",usersList);
```

Now

```
hashMap.get("user")
```

Will return a `List` of `Users`, Now you can use

```
hashMap.get("user").get(0); // to get 0th index user
```